# PHP Form Validation: Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: php, forms, validation, debugging

I am currently learning to validate forms in PHP and parts of my code aren't producing the desired output. I'd want the code to print out `Username cant be blank` when the user submits the form without a username and `Password cant be blank` when the password field is left blank while submitting. i have marked out, with the help of comments, the lines of code that were meant to achieve this goal (refer: `//DOESNT WORK`). Currently, the code is successfully able to display to the user `Username/Password dont match`. I am running the php scripts on XAMPP. My code:

form_with_validation.php

```
<?php 
require_once("included_functions.php");
require_once("validation_functions.php");

$errors = array();
$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   //form was submitted
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

    //Validations
    $fields_required = array("username", "password");
    foreach($fields_required as $field) //DOESNT WORK
    {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if(!has_presence($value))
        {
            $errors[$field] = ucfirst($field) . " cant be blank.";
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
         //try to login
        if($username == "mickey" && $password == "password")
        {   //successful login
            redirect_to("basic.html");
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "Username/Password dont match.";  
        }   
    }

    }
    else {
    $username = "";
    $message = "Please Log in.";
    }
?>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo $message; ?> <br>
    <?php echo form_errors($errors);?>

    <form action="form_with_validation.php" method = "post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username)?>" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" value=""/><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

---

validation_functions.php

```
<?php

//presence
function has_presence($value)
{
    return isset($value) || $value !== "";
}

//string length
    //max length
function has_max_length($value, $max)
{
    return strlen($value) <= $max;
}

//inclusion in a set
function has_inclusion_in($value, $set)
{
    return in_array($value, $set);
}

function form_errors($errors=array())
{
    $output = "";
    if(!empty($errors))
    {
        $output .= "<div class=\"error\">";
        $output .= "Please fix the following errors:"; //NOT WORKING
        $output .= "<ul>";
        foreach($errors as $key => $error)
        {
            $output .= "<li>{$error}<li>";
        }
        $output = "</ul>";
        $output .= "</div>";
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

---

included_functions.php

```
{ 
    return "Hello {$name}!";
}
function redirect_to($new_location)
{
    header("Location: " . $new_location);
    exit;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Just add it:

change

```
$username = trim($_POST["username"]);
$password = trim($_POST["password"]);
```

for:

```
if(isset($username)){
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}else{
    die("Username cant be blank");
}
if(isset($password)){
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}else{
    die("password cant be blank");
}
```

You can change die() will stop php execution, you can just print and manage that error otherwise.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your suggestion has, in a way, hardcoded the error `Username cant be blank.`. Even when i enter the correct username and password; OR even when only the password field is left blank, the error displayed is `Username cant be blank.`

Comment: Seems like your form isnt sending the _POST values